# Inverse Variation Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question came up on my textbook and its confusing me.I know i have to use inverse variation some how but im not sure how to implement it.

Here's the question

> An architect is designing a building. The client has insisted that one of the rooms in the building must
>   2
>   have an area of 48m squared . For ease of design, the length l and the breadth b must each be a whole number of
>   metres. Because of the furniture that must go into the room, no wall may be less than 4 m. What are the possible dimensions of the room?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find two numbers $l$ and $b$ that are

- both whole numbers
- both at least $4$
- multiply to $48$

Think about ways you can factor $48$.